# JSON Validate date on Sharepoint

Tags: json, date, validation, sharepoint

I'm new on JSON script.

I just write on sharepoint 365 online

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=if(@now>=[$StartDate],if(@now<=[$EndDate],'active','non active'),'non active')"
}
```

My problem the result always non active when it saved. I need status will be `active` if date range on current month and will be change automatically to `Non Active` if out of current month

I hope my pic can tell about my problem

Thanks everyone

JSON Validate Date
[image]

Comment: I used your json to do the test, and the result is no problem. The screenshot you provided seems to meet your needs and does not reflect your problem.

Comment: Are you sure? because when I tried status is not active, but i need "Active" when current (today's) date is in between Start date and End Date.

Answer (score 0):

My test result for your reference:
[image]

Comment: Hmm.. I think there is little missing because when i wrote that script not work, but when I try
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(@now >= [$MasaBerlaku] && @now <= [$PeriodeAkhir], 'Active', 'Non Active')",
Problem is field name is not correct and missing "&&" 
Thanks for your  help

Comment: You need to use the internal name in json formatting.

Answer (score 0):

yap, is done .
Thanks for your help and fast responses
This question is solved